# How to fix "Fatal error: Class 'setasign\Fpdi\FpdfTpl' not found on line 25" but i have no code in line 25

Tags: fpdf, fpdi

I came across with same problem of mine but i tried solved it with the given solution in every topic but it seems i cant solve it.
Saying "Class 'setasign\Fpdi\FpdfTpl' not found"

I am new in using this FPDF and FPDI, please help me on solving my problem

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi/fpdi.php');
require_once('fpdi/autoload.php');

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the source file
$pdf->setSourceFile("IBA.pdf");
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');

$pdf->Output();
```

i Just wanted to put watermark on my imported pdf file

Answer (score 0):

Create your one rotation.php file in fpdi folder

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF_Rotate extends FPDF
{
var $angle=0;

function Rotate($angle,$x=-1,$y=-1)
{
    if($x==-1)
        $x=$this->x;
    if($y==-1)
        $y=$this->y;
    if($this->angle!=0)
        $this->_out('Q');
    $this->angle=$angle;
    if($angle!=0)
    {
        $angle*=M_PI/180;
        $c=cos($angle);
        $s=sin($angle);
        $cx=$x*$this->k;
        $cy=($this->h-$y)*$this->k;
        $this->_out(sprintf('q %.5F %.5F %.5F %.5F %.2F %.2F cm 1 0 0 1 %.2F %.2F cm',$c,$s,-$s,$c,$cx,$cy,-$cx,-$cy));
    }
}

function _endpage()
{
    if($this->angle!=0)
    {
        $this->angle=0;
        $this->_out('Q');
    }
    parent::_endpage();
}
}
?>
```

Add this code

```
<?PHP

require('fpdi/rotation.php');

class PDF extends PDF_Rotate
{
function Header()
{
    //Put the watermark
    $this->SetFont('Arial','B',50);
    $this->SetTextColor(255,192,203);
    $this->RotatedText(35,190,'W a t e r m a r k   d e m o',45);
}

function RotatedText($x, $y, $txt, $angle)
{
    //Text rotated around its origin
    $this->Rotate($angle,$x,$y);
    $this->Text($x,$y,$txt);
    $this->Rotate(0);
}
}

// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI();
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set the source file
$pdf->setSourceFile("IBA.pdf");
// import page 1
$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1);
// use the imported page and place it at point 10,10 with a width of 100 mm
$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 10, 10, 100);

// now write some text above the imported page
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetXY(30, 30);
$pdf->Write(0, 'This is just a simple text');

$pdf->Output();  
?>
```

I Hope it will help you

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'FPDI' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\PDF_MAKER\index.php on line 25

Comment: please help me on my problem, i tried to insert FPDI file but saying error set assign Fpdftpl. same problem again

Comment: @Jexten : FPDF to FPDI